# Estilos não se aplicam a elementos vindos via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

Estou montando uma página que é inserido 2 valores. Esses valores vão para uma página `.php` via `AJAX` e em seguida a página retorna todos os registros do banco.

**Função que cadastra os dados:**

```
function adiciona(){

                    var os = $('#icon_telephone').val();;
                    var descricao = $('#icon_prefix').val();;


                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'adiciona.php',
            dataType : 'html',
                        data: {descricao: descricao, os:os},
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("#carrega").show();
                            $("#carrega").hide();
                            console.log(data);
              exibe();
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, desc, err){
                             console.log(xhr);
                             console.log(desc);
                             console.log(err);
                        $('#notification-bar').text("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

**Função que recupera os dados:**

```
  function exibe(){
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      dataType : 'html',
      url: 'exibe.php',
      success: function(data2){
         console.log("dados fun 2"+data2);
         $('#tabeladados').text(data2);
    //     $('#tabeladados').off();
          //     $('#tabeladados').text(data2);
        //  $("#tabeladados").on('load', 'button.actionButton', exibe());
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err){
         console.log(xhr);
         console.log(desc);
         console.log(err);
          $('#notification-bar').text("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }
    });


  }
```

**Problema:**

A saida está normal. Todos os dados que eu preciso são retornados, porém o estilo css da pagina não é aplicado a esses elementos retornados, como o exemplo abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque:

```
$('#tabeladados').text(data2);
```

Por:

```
$('#tabeladados').html(data2);
```

Quando se usa o método `text()`, quer dizer que o texto do elemento será exatamente aquele passado pelo parâmetro, mesmo que seja uma linguagem como o HTML.

Já o `html()` é proprio para receber um parâmetro de string em html, assim ela será lida como código e será implementada na página, assim como o `include` ou `require` do php.

E verifique que a página que recebe esses dados tenha os mesmos arquivos de estilo para que as classes da tabela serem lidas.